# Get node inside div without duplicating

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I have the html code below

```html
<div class = "matches">
<div class = "conf">
Brazil vs. Colombia
</ div>
<div class = "targetHour"> 08:00 pm </ div>
</ div>
</ div>
<div class = "matches">
<div class = "conf">
Chilex Argentina
</ div>
<div class = "targetHour"> 08:00 pm </ div>
</ div>
</ div>
```

I need to get the value of the parent div and the value of the child div, without duplicating the result. Tie the schedule of each game with the respective parent.

This my python code

```py
for nc in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'league-data'}):
    campeonato = nc.text
    for hr in soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'match row cf'}).findAll("div",recursive=False):
        print(campeonato + "|" + hr.text)
```

Comment: Why don't you just make a list of already gathered items and filter from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip()` function to tie matches to corresponding schedule:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''<div class = "conf">
Brazil vs. Colombia
</div>
<div class = "targetHour"> 08:00 pm </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class = "matches">
<div class = "conf">
Chilex Argentina
</div>
<div class = "targetHour"> 08:00 pm </div>
</div>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

for match, hour in zip( soup.select('div.conf'), soup.select('div.targetHour') ):
    print(match.text.strip(), hour.text.strip())
```

Prints:

```
Brazil vs. Colombia 08:00 pm
Chilex Argentina 08:00 pm
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative (assumes even length list)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''<div class = "conf">
Brazil vs. Colombia
</div>
<div class = "targetHour"> 08:00 pm </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class = "matches">
<div class = "conf">
Chilex Argentina
</div>
<div class = "targetHour"> 08:00 pm </div>
</div>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
items = [item.text.strip() for item in soup.select('.conf, .targetHour')]
for i in range(0, len(items), 2):
       print(items[i],items[i+1])
```